# nginx upstream does not be recognized by proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I want my nginx to pass different uri's to different backends,so I thought I do that:

```
    server {
    listen 8090;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log debug;

    location /bar {
        proxy_pass http://backend2;
    }

    location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://backend2;
    }

    location / {        
        proxy_pass http://backend1;
    }
}


upstream backend1 {
    server 10.33.12.41:8080;
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 max_fails=3;
}

upstream backend2 {
    server 10.33.12.41:8080;
    server 10.33.12.43:8080;  
}
```

If I call wget http://mynginxserver:8090/ i get the following:

```
wget http://mynginxserver:8090/
--2015-09-18 11:58:21--  http://mynginxserver:8090/
Connecting to mynginxserver:8090... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://backend1/
[following]
--2015-09-18 11:58:21--  http://backend1/
Resolving backend1 (backend1)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘backend1’
```

Why does it try to resolve backend1? I don't get it. Please help ;)
Regards,
Snooops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Fault:
1st it should have been postet here: serverfault.com
and 2nd its already solved here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/590044/nginx-proxy-pass-config